# Video compression algorithm

Tags: data-compression, computer-graphics

I am working on a project for my CS subject and the topic is Video compression. After theoretical aspect, I want to implement and describe one algorithm that does video compression. I am not sure if these type of questions are allowed here but: what would be the best (the easiest) algorithm to implement for an entry level?

I was looking for some and couldn't find a lot of scientific papers.

Comment: Am I right to think that you didn't find any algorithm and want us to do the job for you ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust Yes, you are right.  I haven't found an algorithm that could be easily implemented in  my paper. My paper shouldn't be about one specific algorithm but I should include a simple implementation. I found a tool called FFmpeg that I could implement in Python but Im uncertain if thats what I'm looking for.

Comment: Possibly consider a simple solution based on local comparison: split the first image in tiles and find the best offsets of the tiles in the second image by template matching in a small neighborhood; repeat with the next images. The compressed stream will be the first image and the set of displacement vectors. When the matching becomes too poor, restart with a full image.

Comment: There are many video compression algorithms and it is easy to find a few with a Google search.  There is even a Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_coding_format, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression#Video, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_codecs#Video_compression_formats, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_file_format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check how JPEG works. For video compression, you have to implement how JPEG works on every frame. There is a great video on YouTube by Reducible on how [JPEG works under the hood](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0me3guauqOU&t=1735s). It explains step by step how the algorithm works but you will have to code it yourself.

Comment: I will take this as an answer to my problem because I actually took this approach.